# Python Not Sending Keys from Dictionary

Tags: python, selenium, dictionary, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a task with selenium.  My code will be broken down into the functions I have defined.

I first read an excel sheet and store that data in a dictionary as strings.

```
def get_excel():
    d = defaultdict(list)

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(sys.argv[1])
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

    row_count = sheet.max_row
    for r in range(2, row_count + 1):
        d[str(sheet.cell(r, 4).value)].append((str(sheet.cell(r, 1).value), str(sheet.cell(r, 2).value), str(sheet.cell(r, 3).value)))
    return d
```

Now I have a separate function that gets the data from excel:

```
def get_emp_data(FirstName, LastName, Email1, EmployeeID, driver):
    f_name = driver.find_element_by_name('f_name')
    l_name = driver.find_element_by_name('l_name')
    email = driver.find_element_by_name('contact_id.email')
    employeeID = driver.find_element_by_name('contact_id.custom')

    time.sleep(5)
    #writing in the fields
    f_name.send_keys(FirstName)
    l_name.send_keys(LastName)
    email.send_keys(Email1)
    employeeID.send_keys(EmployeeID)

    #clicking save button
    save = driver.find_element_by_id('saveButton').click()

    driver.get('link to web address')
```

Next I have a function that does the automation. It passes in the data from the excel sheet.

```
def log_in():
    chrome_path = ("C:\\chromedriver.exe")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("link to web address")

    #setting variables for username and password fields
    username = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')

    #input email and password
    username.send_keys("my email")
    password.send_keys("my password")

    #click submit
    driver.find_element_by_id('submitButton').click()

    #click New Customer Button
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_id('newCustomerButton').click()
    return driver
```

Lastly, I put everything into a main function:

```
def main():
    excel_data = get_excel()
    driver = log_in()
    time.sleep(2)
    for EmployeeID in excel_data:
        try:
            get_emp_data(excel_data[EmployeeID][0], excel_data[EmployeeID][1], excel_data[EmployeeID][2], EmployeeID, driver)
        continue
    except:
        print(FirstName)
```

Then I call main()

```
main()
```

The code is doing everything it should besides writing in the values from excel.  It should log_in(), use the first row of data from excel, click save, go to the next edit page, and use the next row of data from excel and save again until there is no more data in excel.  I think there is something wrong with the way I am passing data into my functions.  Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: No, I am not "great" at programming and not sure about error handling and printing errors.  All i know is that the automation works for everything but sending the text, and that leads me to believe it is the way my dictionary is passing to my functions.

Comment: you can check by printing your first and last name.

Comment: Quick pointer to what could be wrong, you are doing `for EmployeeID in excel_data`, but then not using `EmployeeID` anywhere in the code. You are passing in the exact same 4 values each time you run `log_in`. I think you probably need to separate the insert logic from getting the driver (or work out how to put it in a loop).

Comment: I edited the code and Question with the new code and separated the writing out into a new function.  I also used EmployeeID in my for loop.  Still not working and it did not print out the FirstName.

Comment: Try removing the wrapping `try/except` (as well as the `continue` statement). It's likely swallowing the error that will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Script not Running and Not Giving an Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51937046/python-script-not-running-and-not-giving-an-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved all issues with this error and the code/process of automation works perfectly!  The resolved code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from collections import defaultdict
import openpyxl
import time
import os
import sys
import traceback

def get_excel():
    d = defaultdict(list)

    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(sys.argv[1])
    sheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

    row_count = sheet.max_row
    for r in range(2, row_count + 1):
        d[(sheet.cell(r, 1).value), (sheet.cell(r, 2).value), (sheet.cell(r, 3).value), (sheet.cell(r, 4).value)]
    return d

def get_emp_data(FirstName, LastName, Email1, EmployeeID, driver):
    emp_type = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='name_of_id']/option[text()='option_name']").click()
    f_name = driver.find_element_by_name('f_name')
    l_name = driver.find_element_by_name('l_name')
    email = driver.find_element_by_name('contact_id.email')
    employeeID = driver.find_element_by_name('contact_id.custom')

    f_name.send_keys(FirstName)
    l_name.send_keys(LastName)
    email.send_keys(Email1)
    employeeID.send_keys(EmployeeID)

    save = driver.find_element_by_id('saveButton').click()

def log_in():
    chrome_path = ("C:\chromedriver.exe")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
    driver.get("link to webpage")

    username = driver.find_element_by_name('login')
    password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')

    username.send_keys("username")
    password.send_keys("password")

    driver.find_element_by_id('submitButton').click()

    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_id('newCustomerButton').click()

    return driver

def main():
    excel_data = get_excel()
    driver = log_in()
    time.sleep(3)
    for EmployeeID in excel_data:
        try:
            get_emp_data(EmployeeID[0], EmployeeID[1], EmployeeID[2], EmployeeID[3], driver)
            time.sleep(3)
            driver.get("link to webpage")
            time.sleep(5)
            driver.find_element_by_id('newCustomerButton').click()
            time.sleep(2)
            continue
        except:
            driver.quit()
    driver.get("link to webpage")

main()
```

Comment: Just a quick bit of feedback as I didn't actually close down the tab yesterday, that is definitely not how to use a dict haha, it'd be better as a list (`d[(sheet.cell(r, 1).value), (sheet...` to `lst.append((sheet.cell(r, 1).value), (sheet...`). Also you may not know, instead of `for EmployeeID in excel_data`, you can also do `for FirstName, LastName, Email1, EmployeeID in excel_data`, which then makes it easier to read what is what :)